# Is it bad practice to have a javascript variable the same name as a html ID?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my code:

var p1Display = document.querySelector("#p1Display");

I was wondering if it is bad practice to have the ID and the variable the same name if I am just using the variable to grab the same ID?

Comment: No its not  . It is mentioned nowhere in doc.

Comment: Very opinion based.  For what it's worth, some browsers will allow you to reference an element by its ID in Javascript anyway, so I'd say don't do it as it may interfere with the default behaviour of the browser..  If you want to maintain clarity then do something like `var elements = { p1Display: document.querySelector("#p1Display") }` then you can reference it with `elements.p1Display` - same thing, just a bit safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can potentially cause problems if there are other scripts on the same page which use bad practices and also depend on the global variable referencing the element, *and* you assign a different element to the variable. This is because IDs are (unfortunately) assigned to the `window`:

```js
// This doesn't throw a ReferenceError because window.mydiv exists:
console.log(mydiv);
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
</div>
```

For an example of a problem:

```html
<div id="mydiv">text content!</div>

<script>
// One script written by someone else (not you):
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Expecting text content to be `text content!`');
  console.log(mydiv.textContent);
  console.log('Oops...');
}, 1000);
</script>

<script>
// Your script, which assigns something *other* than `#mydiv` to the variable named `mydiv` in global scope:
const mydiv = document.createElement('div');
mydiv.textContent = 'Another div';
document.body.appendChild(mydiv);
</script>
```

The solution is to:

(1) Don't define variables on the top level, because that can interfere with other scripts' variable names - use an IIFE instead

(2) Don't rely on implicitly referring to properties on `window`, which can result in confusing semantics and hard-to-read code